# how to get SAS to page break correctly, when making an RTF file, to be opened in microsoft word

Tags: sas, sas-ods

I'm using SAS to create a rtf file to be opened in Microsoft word.
I'm using the put statement to create a conditionally generated batch of letters, but when i open the rtf file in Microsoft word, the pages are breaking at all the wrong points for the letters.

I thought at the end of each letter if I have:

```
if last.myvariable then put _page_;
```

that would force it to the next page, but when I open the rtf file in Microsoft word the page breaks don't seem to be working.

What is the easiest way I can make sas page break in an rtf file to be opened in Microsoft word?

Comment: `_PAGE_` is the automatic variable that indicates *where* a page break has occurred, it doesn't set a page break.

Answer (score 1):

You can create page breaks at your desired observation range by creating flags

```
data page;
set dataset end=eof;`your final report dataset`
p=ceil(_n_/10);`Desired observation range`
if eof then lastrec=1;
run;


ods rtf file="path.rtf";
  proc report data=page;
  column lastrec p x;
  define lastrec/display noprint;
  define p/order noprint;
  define x/display;
  break after p/page;
  break after _page_/left;
  run;
ods rtf close;
```

The above code prints 10 observation per page in your rtf output.